# Date doesn't appears in my view with DataFormatString for MVC4 DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have some issue with displaying date correctly, using the MVC4 DateTime object.

In the controller, I set my date from a correct value from my database : Birthdate = person.Birthdate

In ViewModel:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "DD/mm/YY", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true)]
public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }
```

In View:

```
@using (Html.BeginHorizontalControlFor(m => m.Birthdate))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Birthdate)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Birthdate)
}
```

Output:

```
<input class="text-box single-line input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Birthdate must be a date." id="Birthdate" name="Birthdate" type="datetime" value="DD/mm/YY">
```

Where is my date value? Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DD/mm/YY` is the wrong format - you've got the case wrong for all components. You should use `dd/MM/yy` (or something similar; personally I'd recommend using `yyyy` instead of `yy`). See the [MSDN documentation for custom date/time formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for more details.

Also note that this is very culture-specific - are you sure that's an appropriate format for all the cultures you're targeting? (Using some sort of calendar control would be better from a usability perspective, I suspect.)

Answer (score 0):

I've had to modify the syntax for DataFormatString bit on that attribute to get it to work. 
Try:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}")]
```